# How to get jquery variable childeren?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a method that accepts an `id` as a parameter for my function:

```
function exportDetails($div) {
    $($div).each(function () {
        alert(this.id);
});
```

**I need to get all the table's `id`'s that are within this `div`,** something similar to this:

```
function exportDetails($div) {
    $($div > table).each(function () {
        alert(this.id);
});
```

Here is how I am calling the function and each of the itemDetails have dynamically generated tables and I need to get their id's since they are all unique:

```
exportDetails.apply(this, [$('#itemDetails')]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: So what's your issue?

Comment: Is this your real code? If so, it's riddled with typos, and would throw errors in the developer console.  Also, you could / should set up a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for us to work with.

Comment: @NickZuber please read again

Comment: @cale_b no errors are being thrown (the second part doesn't even compile so it's not in my code. I had to scrub some of this just in case.

Comment: @masta_coda Why doesn't the method you suggested work in your situation?

Comment: What has this got to do with c#?

Comment: @NickZuber it doesn't work because it looks at table as a globally declared variable. I want to get the children table id's from $div. $div is a variable... typically it would do something like this:  $('#someDiv > table) and that would get all the table children of that div...

Comment: @evolutionxbox nothing at all. it was an accidental tag

Comment: @masta_coda ah. No problem

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
function exportDetails($div) {
    return [].map.call($div.children('table'), function(table) {
        return table.id;
    });
}
```

i.e. just return an array containing the `.id` of every `table` element found as an immediate descendant of `$div`.

Comment: use `table[id]` as the selector. Drops all empty-string values and is cheaper than post-processing the result.

Comment: @Thomas ah, you mean as a selector to mean "only return tables that have an `id` attribute" ?   Fair comment, but unnecessary if the OP's mark up guarantees that every table already has an ID.

Answer (score 0):

You code is not formatted correctly. Also, I don't know if you are feeding this function a group of tables that are inside of your $div parameter. Here are some options.

```
// this works if you pass in an element with nested table that have ids. 

function exportTableToCSV($div) {
    $($div+ ' > table').each(function () {
        alert( $(this).attr('id') );
    });
}

// this works if you want to get all the HTML elements with an id or if you want to get all the ids of elements which also have the same class assigned to them.

function exportTableToCSV($div) {
    $($div).each(function () {
        alert( $(this).attr('id') );
    });
}

exportTableToCSV('div');

// or

exportTableToCSV('.yourClass');
```

Comment: please, don't use `$(this).attr('id')` - that's a massive jQuery code smell

Comment: the first thing didn't work. it wouldn't compile. I just need to get the tables ids that are dynamically being created on page load.

Comment: Create a selector that grabs the tables then pass that into the function. Use the second method. Also how are your tables being dynamically created. You could just grab the id when it is dynamically created and push that value into an array. I'd have to know how these tables are created though.